# gradually reduce text size in adobe illustrator

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator

how can you gradually reduce the size of a text in photoshop or illustrator? ie..it should start from a higher font size and end in a lower one.

Comment: Can this question be transfered to http://photo.stackexchange.com/?